# rlike not working for a snowpark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to fetch records having the string 'o' in a dataframe column but no records are showing up.
Currently in column 'Variant_nm' in  dataframe I have

```
  Junk_df1=df.filter(col('Variant_Nm')=='Control')
```

**Variant_Nm**
Control
Control

But the following code is showing 0 records:

```
Junk_Count=df.filter(col('Variant_Nm').rlike('o'))
```

Now when I attach rlike('o) no records show up but I can see values present with 'o' in this column.

I will be using rlike to identify special characters for this column but this simple test itself is failing. What should I modify to make it work?

Comment: You can do `df.filter(col('Variant_Nm').contains('o'))` if you want the match to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

[RLIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike#usage-notes) requires putting the wild card tokens at the beging/end of the string

so you example is the same as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE Variant_Nm = 'o'
```

to make it how you want the SQL would need to be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE Variant_Nm RLIKE '.*o.*'
```

therefore your data frame filter should most likely be:

```
Junk_Count=df.filter(col('Variant_Nm').rlike('.*o.*'))
```

The other thing to note is when your dataframe code does not work as planned, jump into the query history, and look at the SQL run, and get that working, and then step back into the abstract layer and getting to generating the good SQL again. Also if you can put `/* comments */` into your into chain like your filters, you can find the generated SQL easier.